# How to repair broken package dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I have a remote Ubuntu server. When I'm running `apt install -f` I'm getting this message:

```
sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists ... Done 
......
The following packages were installed automatically and are no longer required.:
  binutils distro-info-data emacsen-common fonts-dejavu-core foomatic-db grub-pc-bin kbd keyutils
  lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6 lib32tinfo5 libaspell15 libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data
.....
  libsnmp-base libtiff5 libtirpc1 libwrap0 lockfile-progs mc-data mime-support p7zip xkb-data
To remove them, use «sudo apt autoremove».
Packages to be REMOVED:
  acpi-support-base acpid adduser anacron ansible apt apt-utils aptitude aspell aspell-en aspell-ru
  astra-extra astra-safepolicy astra-version atftp bash bash-completion blends-tasks bsd-mailx
  ca-certificates cdebconf:i386 chkrootkit console-setup console-setup-linux cron cryptsetup
.....
  logrotate logtail lsb-release man-db mc mime-construct mount myspell-ru ntfs-3g ntp openprinting-ppds
  openssh-client openssh-server openssh-sftp-server openssl:i386 p7zip-full p7zip-rar passwd:i386 perl
  perl-base perl-modules-5.24 perl-openssl-defaults poppler-data procps python python-cffi-backend
  python-crypto python-cryptography python-enum34 python-httplib2 python-idna python-ipaddress
  python-jinja2 python-kerberos python-markupsafe python-minimal python-netaddr python-paramiko
  python-pkg-resources python-pyasn1 python-selinux python-setuptools python-six python-xmltodict
  python-yaml python2.7 python3 python3-minimal python3.5 python3.5-minimal quota readline-common
  rsyslog snmp sudo systemd systemd-sysv sysvinit-utils tar:i386 tasksel tasksel-data tcl-expect tzdata
  ucf udev ufw util-linux util-linux-locales wamerican wget:i386 wpasupplicant
ATTENTION: These essential packages will be removed.
DO NOT do this if you DO NOT imagine all the possible consequences!
  apt adduser (вследствие apt) gnupg (вследствие apt)
  init-system-helpers (вследствие apt) bash dash (вследствие bash) dpkg:i386
  ia32-libs (вследствие dpkg:i386) tar:i386 (вследствие dpkg:i386) e2fsprogs
  libblkid1 (вследствие e2fsprogs) libuuid1 (вследствие e2fsprogs)
  util-linux (вследствие e2fsprogs) grep gzip init systemd-sysv (вследствие init)
  perl-base (вследствие init-system-helpers) login libpam0g (вследствие login)
  libpam-runtime (вследствие login) libpam-modules (вследствие login) mount
  libmount1 (вследствие mount) sysvinit-utils libfdisk1 (вследствие util-linux)
0 updated, 0 new packages installed, 227 packages marked for deletion, and 0 packages not updated.
not fully installed or removed 42 packages.
After this operation, the amount of occupied disk space will be reduced by 2 096 MB.
What you want to do can have undesirable consequences.
To continue, enter the phrase: “Yes, do as I say!”
```

How can I repair this issue?

I think that somebody installed an incompatible package with `dpkg` and broke some dependencies.

Upd.: On this server i`m dont have any internet connection. I`m can connect to them only at ssh via some vpn.

Comment: The output so far doesn't look like "somebody install incompatible package." It seems more like a Minimal or Netboot system that has been built up, but the top-level applications have been removed. (Re-)installing a desktop metapackage (`ubuntu-desktop`, `xubuntu-desktop`, etc) is one way to stabilize the system.

Comment: `dpkg --print-architecture` please. Many packages loose their manual flag.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try the following:

1. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
2. `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade`
3. `sudo apt -f install`

Comment: Instead of just asking to try, could you _explain_ why this should help (and not make it worse)?

Comment: yes , as I see in packages some packages are 32bit and are going to be uninstalled but some of them are the system packages that must not removed. So when you do 1. sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386   it will add architecture 32bit to system if someone accidentally removed it. Second point will get updated package list and then it will upgrade the packages and last command will fix package related issue only if issue is left. It will not cause any errors or system loss.

Comment: Thanks all for answer ! Big Thanks ! Sorry but i`m forgett write that this server doesnt have any internet connection.  So i` cant do 2. sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade.

Comment: Is your problem solved @Sergey ?  You have to connect it from an internet connection and do "sudo service network-manager restart"

Comment: i mean that this ubuntu server locate at some local network, i`m can connect to  vpn , ssh. i`m cant just run apt  update && apt upgrade and so. I`m can install some app only from deb pkg (copy them by scp).

Comment: No @PrakashLakhara problem didnt solved. I mean that is that server didnt have any internet connection. They located at some local network behind firewall\ vpn and  so. I`m can install any pakage only from deb pkg, which i need first copy by scp. I think i need change my question for that: how repair broken dependencies on local ubuntu server.

Comment: me be i need remove some pkg by dpkg tool, but i think that it can broken this server.

Comment: some packages needs some dependecies that downloads only when a pc is connected to internet.

Comment: So that i cant repair this broken dependencies ? Anywere Thanks for answer!